# Define a TypeScript type from the values of an object array

Tags: typescript

Given the following array:

```js
type Currency = {
  text: string,
  value: string
}

let currencies: Currency[] = [ 
  { text: 'American dollars', value: 'USD' },
  { text: 'Euros', value: 'EU' }
]
```

These currencies might come from a database or a web service, but will have that shape, that is: `{ text: string, value: string }[]`.

Is there some way to define a variable like this:

```js
let currency: 'USD' | 'EU'
```

That is, a type which should be the value property of one item of the `currencies` array.

What would be the right way to define these types so I can enforce that `currency` holds a valid currency value?

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the type from the value, rather than defining the type and using it to _check_ the value: https://tsplay.dev/wRJrYw

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because if you define a union of string literal types and use that to check the value, then you have written all of your string literals twice, violating the DRY principle.

Comment: @kaya3 I was looking more for _the OP's_ specific constraints, but: although it's true that in trivial cases you end up writing the same values twice, we're rarely in the trivial cases. When you add a new entry into this list, for example, is it more useful for the compiler to just accept that it must be valid or tell you you've typed `value: 'UE'` not the intended `value: 'EU'`? Is it easier to review the literal type or the whole list for incorrect values?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Looks to me like this array is intended to define what currencies are allowed in the program. Presumably it's declared as a value rather than a type because it needs to be used at runtime. That's a pretty common thing to do, and it's not an antipattern.

Comment: @kaya3 you might well be right, but again I asked to clarify the OP's case. I didn't say it was an anti pattern, but neither is it the case that DRY is always the right thing to do; these are heuristics, not commandments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I tried to clarify the question. Maybe what I'm trying to do is not possible with Typescript, as it is not related with the Currency type but with the contents of the currency array.
I'm trying to find a type that means that the variable matches the property 'value' of an item from the currencies array.

Comment: If you don't have that data at compile time then no, you can't do that; TypeScript **does not** exist at runtime, types are _erased_ in compilation.

Comment: Yes, I understand that typescript is not meant to do anything at runtime, I just wanted to know if there was a way to express that relation, in spite typescript nor being able to enforce it, same way that at runtime you can add keys to and object, but tell typescript that a type should match one of those keys with the keyof type operator

Comment: If that data's coming at runtime you'll presumably have e.g. `interface Currency { text: string; value: string; }` being passed as a generic type somewhere to make access type-safe, in which case you could express that relationship with `let currency: Currency['value']`. But that would just be string, if you want to do something that prevents primitives being used where they're the right type but not semantically correct, the idea you're looking for is _branded types_.

Answer (score 2):

Sure can.

```
const currencies = [ 
  { text: 'American dollars', value: 'USD' },
  { text: 'Euros', value: 'EU' }
] as const

type CurrencyName = (typeof currencies)[number]['value'] // "USD" | "EU"

let currency: CurrencyName = 'USD' // works
```

First of all, `currencies` *needs* to be a `const` and `as const` this tells typescript that these are constant literals and not just any old `string`.

Then:

- You can get the type of a value with `typeof` in `typeof currencies`.
- This is an array. Array's are indexed by `number`, so `MyArray[number]` gets all members of that array as a union.
- All union members have a `value` property, you can drill into that to get a union of all possible types at that `value` property.
- The result is `"USD" | "EU"`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCuAnRBTMwCWKIwLwwG0YBYAKBhgG8YoUAPKALhgHIBBAWxUQ2AEMwMACYgANqL6IILADQwAbn1HwUzFgFUAygBEWMAL4yyFarQZqAokhDS5i5atYX1e-WQC6MPjlCQoZMigATwAHFBgAYSRUdCCAOT4uPBgACmCwkAAzOGi0TGwASgIweA4AI253AhZ7FRZPAHoGmAAiLW0WmAAfVucWgNJRFFgEZDyg5iix2ISk-A0dPSaYAHcQRABrCCA)

---

> "The data may eventually come from a database or a web service, but it will still be an array of Currency. Is there some way to let typescript know that currency is meant to match the value prop of an item from the currencies array?"

Not really. Typescript is structural, not nominal. That means that if two types have the same shape, then it considers them the same type.

So if these records are stored in a database, the `value` column will be typed as `string` since you can't know the union of values at compile time. And that means any `string` will be considered the same as that type.

To elaborate on this further would drift into a totally separate SO question. So feel free to ask another!

Comment: Note that `as const` has other effects - the type of `currencies` becomes `readonly [{ readonly text: "American dollars"; readonly value: "USD"; }, { readonly text: "Euros"; readonly value: "EU"; }]` which may not be quite what's wanted (e.g. I'd guess the `text` is really just a `string`) or actively prevent desired behaviour (e.g. you can't `.push` a new entry into it).

Comment: All true, Jon. But this is still a pretty useful pattern for a `constants/currencies.ts` file that provides constant lookup values without having to manually type those constants. But if this array expects any mutation, than you'll definitely want to write the type first, and then make your values use that type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer. It helped me a lot. I updated the question. The data may eventually come from a database or a web service, but it will still be an array of Currency. Is there some way to let typescript know that currency is meant to match the value prop of an item from the currencies array?

Comment: @opensas Not really. Typescript is structural, not nominal. That means that if two types have the same shape, then it considers them the same type. If these records are stored in a database, the `value` column will be typed as `string` since you can't know the union of values at compile time. And that means any `string` will be considered the same as that type. But either way, I think that's a totally separate SO question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, please add this last consideration to your answer (very clear explanation) so I can accept the answer